# How to install executable files of c# windows application in mac os

Tags: c#, .net, macos, installation

I am developing an application using C# for the front end (Visual Studio 2008) and SQL Server 2008 R2 as back-end.

I would like to know if the exe will run on Mac OS after compilation. Or is there any particular setting to add?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you should look to [mono project](http://www.mono-project.com/). It's open source cross platform .NET framework.